# Adding buttons to a FileMaker portal to jump to the related records

Tags: filemaker

I've just started in FM 14. I have a client table and a project table. When I look at a client entry I have a portal that shows me the titles of the projects they have commissioned. I'd like to be able to click on one of the projects in that portal list and be taken to the layout that contains all of the other fields in that project record. Can this be done? Is this enough information?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set the button action as a script step "Go to Related Record". In this script step, set the table as "projects" and select the layout you would like to go.

Answer (score -2):

I would stay away from GoToRelatedRecord. I usually just grab the ID from the item in the portal, then search for that item on a new layout, then do whatever I planned on doing. It's safer. With GoToRelatedRecord you can never really control what happens.

Comment: This is pure nonsense. Consider removing this entry.  GTRR is a basic FileMaker script step.

Comment: It's not nonsense. It can fail and not even let you know. You will only know the layout or table is missing if you open the script step and check. Also, I am much more of a fan of being able to control my found set.